# JVisualVm on Linux

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I'm trying to do some profiling on an app and i'm having some problems with jvisualvm, basically whenever i start the app in debug mode jvisualvm gives me this error: [image]

I've seen that on windows the way to solve this si to delete the folder called hsperfdata but on linux i don't have that folder :( or at least i can't find it.

Also, i'm using sts as ide if it matters in some way.

Comment: This error often arises when there is more than one JDK or JRE defined.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have more than one jdk installed so i'll try again after removing it